# Не могу понять что надо использовать

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть у меня задание и я не как не могу его сделать, а именно я не понимаю что надо использовать, чтобы вывести ключ и значение одновременно.

Задание вот:

> Любимые числа:
>
> Используйте словарь для хранения любимых чисел.
>
> Возьмите пять имен и используйте их как ключи словаря. Придумайте
>   любимое число для каждого человека и сохраните его как значение в
>   словаре.
>
> Выведите имя каждого человека и его любимое число.
>
> Чтобы
>   задача стала более интересной, опросите нескольких друзей и соберите
>   реальные данные для своей программы.

Comment: `print(*[ [k, v] for k, v in {'Vasya': 5, 'Petya': 2,}.items() ], sep='\n')`

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic = {"Имя_1": 8, "Имя_2": 5, "Имя_3": 13, "Имя_4": 7, "Имя_5": 5}

for name in dic:
    print(name, dic[name])
```

---

Данные словаря пишутся в фигурных скобках (`{}`), отделенны запятыми (`,`), всегда в форме *ключ*, двоеточие (`:`) и затем *значение ключа*.

Когда вы хотите знать значение какого-то ключа, запишите за имя словаря  имя ключа в квадратных скобках (`[]`), например (в моем примере) значение ключа `"Имя_3"`, т.е. число `13`, получите выражением `dic["Имя_3"]`.